# case statement not executing properly when the * option is included

Tags: bash, case-statement

i have a case script as follow :

```
 for i in "$@"; do
arg=( $@ )
    case $i in
 --string)
          for ((i=0; i<${#arg[@]}; i++)) ; do
           if [ "${arg[$i]}" == "--string" ] ; then
                ((i++))
                 STRING=${arg[$i]}
           fi
          done
          ;;
*)
          print_help
          exit
          ;;
  esac
done
```

when i run ./test --some_command --string pattern ; it prints the help option.
When i run ./test --some_command --string pattern without the *) option in the string, it works.

Can you please tell me how to fix this.

Another example :

```
#!/bin/bash

test(){

        echo i am testing this now
}

print_help()
{
  echo help
}

for i in "$@"; do
arg=( $@ )
    case $i in
 --string)
          for ((i=0; i<${#arg[@]}; i++)) ; do
           if [ "${arg[$i]}" == "--string" ] ; then
                ((i++))
                 STRING=${arg[$i]}
           fi
          done
                echo $STRING
          ;;
 --test)
        test
        ;;

 *)
          print_help
          exit
          ;;
  esac
done
```

when i run ./test --string pattern --test. it prints
pattern
help

Comment: I tried this script exactly as is, and it worked just fine for me.

Comment: If the argument to `--string` is an unquoted shell pattern, it will be expanded to multiple arguments by the shell before your script sees it; one of the resulting words is likely to be an unrecognized argument.

Comment: please refer to the other example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the for loop gets to "pattern", it is not covered by a case branch so it hits the default branch and prints the help. You have to iterate over the arguments in a smarter way. Replace for `for` loop with

```
while (( $# > 0 )); do
    arg=$1
    shift
    case $arg in
        --string) STRING=$1; shift; echo "$STRING" ;;
        --some-command) : ;;
        --) break ;;
        *) print_help; exit ;;
    esac
done
```